# Array Structure sorting

Tags: arrays, pointers, structure

I having trouble sorting this code,  ugh

any insight would be tremendous

Structure :

```
// Test Score

struct testData  //declare testScore
```

{

```
int score ;// score of each student 
string student; // Student name 

};

//  Functions prototypes

void sSort(struct testData * , int);
void displaySorts(struct testData *, int);
double avgScore(double);
```

This is part that i'm having the most trouble with

sort code
   //  Sort  Functions

```
void  sSort(struct testData *gradDat, int SIZE)
{
int scan, minIndex, minValue;

for ( scan=0 ; scan < (SIZE - 1); scan++)
{
    minIndex = scan;
    minValue = (*(gradDat+ scan)).score;

    for(int index = scan + 1; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        if ((*(gradDat + scan)).score < minValue)
         { 
            minValue = (*(gradDat + scan)).score;
            minIndex = index;
         }

    }
    //gradDat[minIndex] = *(gradDat + scan);
    //(*(gradDat + scan)).score = minValue;

    testData temp = gradDat[scan];
    gradDat[minIndex] = gradDat[scan];
    gradDat[scan] = temp;
 }

// Check sort - bu hiding now
for (int count = 0; count < SIZE ; count++)
{
    cout << (*(gradDat + count)).student <<" "<< (*(gradDat + count)).score;
    cout << endl;
}  


}
```

i changed the code per another post but it didnt help

any thoughts?

Comment: what problem are you running into? and what exactly do you want do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mistaking the loop indices. The inner loop should be:

```
for(int index = scan + 1; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if ((*(gradDat + index)).score < minValue)
     { 
        minValue = (*(gradDat + index)).score;
        minIndex = index;
     }

}
```

You are using `index` for that loop, not `scan`.

And also there's a mistake when the values are swapped:

```
testData temp = gradDat[minIndex];
gradDat[minIndex] = gradDat[scan];
gradDat[scan] = temp;
```

PS: And maybe you'd like to consider using array notation to make the code more readable: `gradDat[index].score`.